# Stopping the iPhone UITableView from scrolling to the top

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm writing some code that causes a UITableView to change it's height, ie changing the value of tableView.frame.size.heigh. Every time I change the height it causes the entire table to scroll all the way to the top of the table. At which point I have to call scrollToRowAyIndexPath on the table to get the table view back to where it was.

Does anyone know of a way to get the table to stop scroll when its height is changed?

Thanks in advance - AYAL

Comment: Can you be more specific about the code you're calling? In my experience, resizing the height of a tableview doesn't typically cause this. Also note SDK version, please.

Comment: The problem I was having was that when I left a view with the UITableView and then returned the table would display the very top element of the table. All I had to do was add code to the viewWillAppear method of the controller and I was able to have the view start at the very bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, don't let it get assigned automatically (i.e. `sizeToFit`). UITableView can be very unpredictable if you are not very specific and if you don't override certain methods.
I had a unique problem with tableView scrolling back up to top automatically after I called `[tableView reloadData]`; This problem was unique because it only happened on iPad mini and iOS 8, every other device and OS was working properly. Hope it helps someone...